# Xcode 13 - Completion not working after '@' when SwiftUI is imported

Tags: swiftui, xcode13

This is only happens on one machine, others seems to be better.
With SwiftUI, no code completion is shown after '@'. Anything like `@State`, `@Published`, `@Binding`, will not complete at all.
If I remove `import SwiftUI`, completion will start working, but will stop once the import statement returns.
If I only have `import Combine`, then all the `SwiftUI` is working, but not the `Combine` (`@State` will complete, `@Published` will not).

I tried (while restarting the Mac after each time), toggle code completion, cleared all DerivedData, re-downloading Xcode. Not sure what else can be done.

(While it only happens on one machine, M1 mac, other people had some other things like completion after `@S` but none after `@St`).

[image]

Comment: That has been happening a lot to me on Xcode 13RC. It is better after a restart...

Comment: I've done like 50 restarts (something I rarely do). Downloaded Xcode from Apple and back from the AppStore, created another user and test Xcode there.. Nothing works....

Comment: I said better, not perfect. Code completion in this version is not up to standard... just keep typing and build it.

Comment: That's encouraging, it means it will probably be fixed in a following version. I actually created code snippets to compensate. And of course, it ok to just type it. It's just the feeling that it's broken that sucks.

Comment: Sadly, there is a lot broken in this release. There have been at least two bugs in Xcode that I am aware of in SwiftUI that were asked here last week.